# trouble extending events on @types/leaflet typings for plugin

Tags: typescript, leaflet, definitelytyped

I am unable to add event registration for events to `Map` or `Layer` for a leaflet plugin. The `Evented` class from `@types/leaflet` exposes the events on `Map` AND `Layer`, but some of the events I need to add are `Map` only or `Layer` only events.  [Stackblitz for reference](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-bgc7sx?file=leaflet-plugin.d.ts)

```
import * as L from 'leaflet';

declare module 'leaflet' {

    /**
     * Extends built in leaflet map.
     */
    interface Map {
        on(type: 'pm:globaldrawmodetoggled', fn: (event: { enabled: boolean, shape: string, map: L.Map }) => this, context?: any): this;
    }

}
```

results in the error

```
Interface 'Map' incorrectly extends interface 'Evented'.
  Types of property 'on' are incompatible.
    Type '(type: "pm:globaldrawmodetoggled", fn: (event: { enabled: boolean; shape: string; map: Map; }) => this, context?: any) => this' is not assignable to type '{ (type: string, fn: LeafletEventHandlerFn, context?: any): this; (type: "baselayerchange" | "overlayadd" | "overlayremove", fn: LayersControlEventHandlerFn, context?: any): this; (type: "layeradd" | "layerremove", fn: LayerEventHandlerFn, context?: any): this; (type: "zoomlevelschange" | ... 18 more ... | "predrag"...'.
      Types of parameters 'fn' and 'fn' are incompatible.
        Types of parameters 'event' and 'event' are incompatible.
          Type '{ enabled: boolean; shape: string; map: Map; }' is missing the following properties from type 'LeafletEvent': type, target, sourceTarget, propagatedFrom, layer(2430)
```

Is there something I'm overlooking here, or maybe something I could try to get changed upstream to allow `@types/leaflet` to be more compatible with additional types provided by plugins?